# Connecting flight,stop over to Canada,do I need a USVisa?

Tags: visas, air-travel, usa

Hi I'm a Filipino living here in Santiago chile,and I'm traveling to Canada,all the connecting flight is need to stop to USA,so my question,Do I need a USA visa in order for me to get a in,and stop over to USA before continuing my flight bound to canada?

Comment: Sorry new members can not read or doesn't not know the answers ,,if the question is posted long time ago,,thanks

Comment: So can you please let me know the answers regards this question?im new member so I don't have any idea about those previous posted concern,,thank you

Comment: can you not click the question? It's publicly visible to all (I can log out and still see it, so it's not hidden).